# Double sided inequality with square root function

Tags: inequality

I wish to solve for the bound on $x$ when it satisfies the following equation,
$$-6\leq\sqrt{x-4}-2x\leq4$$
I tried solving it in the following manner
$$-6\leq\sqrt{x-4}-2x\leq4$$
$$\implies -6+2x\leq\sqrt{x-4}\leq 4+2x$$
$$\implies 36-24x+4x^2\leq x-4\leq 16+16x+4x^2$$
$$\implies 40-24x\leq x-4x^2\leq 20+16x$$
I could come up till this step, but now if I take the part which is linear in $x$ in the middle either from the left inequality or right inequality still their remain a $x$ part in the right or the left inequality respectively.

I am stuck at this point and any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as two separate inequalities:
(a) $\sqrt{x-4}\le 2x+4$ and (b) $\sqrt{x-4}\ge 2x-6$. Note that you must have $x\ge 4$ for both to make sense; so we assume that $x\ge 4$ from now on.

The first inequality is equivalent then to $x-4\le (2x+4)^2$, i.e. $4x^2+15x+12\ge 0$ which is always true.

The second inequality holds when either $x\le 3$, which is impossible due to our assumption, or $x-4\ge (2x-6)^2$, i.e. $4x^2 - 25x + 40\le 0$, which is never true (check the discriminant!)

Hence there are no solutions.

Comment: (+1) but your paragraph about the first inequality is useless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some more similar kind of inequalities and would like to know is there any way other way to solve them in a more compact manner ( I mean without breaking the less than equal part and the greater than equal part and treat them separately).

Answer (score 1):

In order for $\sqrt{x-4}$ to be a real number, we need $x \ge 4$.  But then $\sqrt{x-4} - 2x \ge -6$ cannot be satisfied, since $$x - 4 \ge (2x-6)^2 = 4x^2 - 24x + 36$$ implies $$0 \ge 4x^2 - 25x + 40 = \left(2x - \frac{25}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{15}{16} \ge \frac{15}{16},$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$-6+2x\le \sqrt{x-4}\le  4+2x$$
$\mathrm{If}\:a\le \:u\le \:b\:\mathrm{then}\:a\le \:u \,\,\, \mathrm{and}\,\,\, \:u\le \:b$. Hence

$$\sqrt{x-4}\ge \:-6+2x$$
$$\mathrm{If}\:\sqrt{f\left(x\right)}\ge \:g\left(x\right)\:\mathrm{then}\:g\left(x\right)<0\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:g\left(x\right)\ge \:0$$
For $-6+2x<0\implies x<3$. If $-6+2x\geq 0\implies S=\emptyset$.  Combine the intervals: $\mathrm{no\:solution\:for}\:x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\sqrt{x-4}\le \:4+2x$$ have like solution $x\geq 4$. But  $\{x\geq 4\}\cup \emptyset=\emptyset$.

$-6\leq\sqrt{x-4}-2x\leq4$ have no solution forall $x \in \Bbb R$.